# How to setup a Ethereum private chain by using pyethapp?

Tags: private-blockchain, pyethapp

For some reason, I want want setup an Ethereum private chain by using Pyethapp instead of Geth.

Any suggestion any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a github repo I created to quickly make a private ethereum network for testing/development:

https://github.com/chafey/ethereum-private-network

It uses doesn't use pytheapp, but it might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You might wanted to check [Running a private network](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/wiki/Running-a-private-network)

> If you want to test or play around with Ethereum, you can follow [`this guide`](https://github.com/konradkonrad/docker-pyeth-cluster) to setup docker with a private Ethereum network.

### [Running a private network Guide](https://github.com/konradkonrad/docker-pyeth-cluster)

1. Set up Docker and pull the container
2. Run it `docker-compose scale bootstrap=1 miner=2 eth=3`
3. More Info [here](https://github.com/konradkonrad/docker-pyeth-cluster#simple)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Your linked guide is a docker cluster on github. Does that really answer the question?

Comment: @5chdn yeah, I understand your point. The docker solution is the only thing they got documented atm. I also understand that link only answer is not welcomed here. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

From [this tutorial](https://github.com/konradkonrad/docker-pyeth-cluster/blob/master/simple/docker-compose.yml), I copied the init command to run my single private node. For example:

```
pyethapp -c eth.network_id=1337 -c node.privkey_hex=091bd6067cb4612df85d9c1ff85cc47f259ced4d4cd99816b14f35650f59c322 -b enode://288b97262895b1c7ec61cf314c2e2004407d0a5dc77566877aad1f2a36659c8b698f4b56fd06c4a0c0bf007b4cfb3e7122d907da3b005fa90e724441902eb19e@localhost:30303 -c eth.genesis_hash=283bd9430c5f3114872f93beefe99d6626980b3a4a18a44ddd27749cd89688f2 -d ~/local-pyethapp run --fake
```

After initiate, hit Ctrl-C and Enter to access pyethapp console. Then you can play around with your single node private network.

Comment: Is the entrypoint field in your tutorial link is the place  where the node's code is taken (so it can be changed to other source codes?)